# What is the equivalent of pathmunge() in csh?

Tags: csh, array

In bash, a common function implemented in e.g. /etc/bashrc is `pathmunge()`, which appends or prepends a path to `PATH` if it isn't already listed among the elements in `PATH`.

Example:

```
$ echo $PATH
/bin:/usr/bin
$ pathmunge /home/me/bin
$ echo $PATH
/home/me/bin:/bin:/usr/bin
$ pathmunge /home/me/bin
$ echo $PATH
/home/me/bin:/bin:/usr/bin
```

The naive way to add a path would be as follow:

```
$ echo $PATH
/bin:/usr/bin
$ PATH=/home/me/bin:$PATH
$ echo $PATH
/home/me/bin:/bin:/usr/bin
$ PATH=/home/me/bin:$PATH
$ echo $PATH
/home/me/bin:/home/me/bin:/bin:/usr/bin
```

I know very little about csh, and I just want to do this simple thing: add a path to a list if it's not already there. I am aware that csh uses `path` rather than `PATH` and that is is a proper csh array.

Maybe csh has some array function like `if !(foobar in $path) then blah` that makes a function like `pathmunge()` unnecessary. In that case, that is the correct answer.

Comment: "Consider not using csh" is an automatic -1 ...

Comment: If you `echo $PATH | grep /home/me/bin` then you can check the return code and add the new path only if it non-zero (ie string not found).

Comment: @clacke putting "example is automatic -1" in the comments is not constructive. The question states you'd like to use `csh`, if someone asks what your purpose is (if it's not outlined in the question), you may get answers that are better than using that command. It doesn't make them less valid, but you can indicate you're looking to use that specific command.

Comment: csh questions everywhere on the internet tend to get an automatic "consider using bash", indeed I found one of the near the top to a question similar to this one. just pre-empting some of the noise.

Comment: Grepping can easily give false positives, also I would like to avoid going into a sub-process if possible. The cleanest bash solution uses `:$PATH:` and a `case` statement that makes `*:$1:*` match a no-op, to avoid shelling out. Since csh supports arrays I'm hoping there are actual array operators, unfortunately the man page and http://tcsh.org/ wiki are silent on "array", "list" or "sequence", except that they say that this or that special variable is an array.

Comment: If I'm shelling out anyway, maybe the easiest way is to just do the processing in bash. :-)

Comment: Ok, according to http://grymoire.com/Unix/CshTop10.txt csh doesn't even support functions, so maybe I'm way out on a limb here already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official workaround for missing array management in `csh` is to use the [Modules](http://modules.sourceforge.net/) system ([environment-modules](https://packages.debian.org/stable/environment-modules) package on Debian).

Answer (score 0):

I finally went with the solution of shelling into bash, because it doesn't seem possible to solve this within the ''csh'' language.

`~/bin/munge_echo`:

```
#!/bin/bash

function munge() {
  case ":$1:" in
    *:$2:*) echo "$1" ;;
    ::) echo "$2" ;;
    *) echo "$2:$1" ;;
  esac
}

munged="$1"

shift

while [ -n "$1" ]; do
  munged="$(munge "$munged" "$1")"
  shift
done

echo "$munged"
```

`~/.csh`:

```
setenv PATH `~/bin/munge_echo "$PATH" ~/.local/bin ~/bin`
```

Comment: [Wouldn't be the first time.](http://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/misc/csh.html)

Comment: Yeah, but that's also why it's so difficult to find information on csh on the internet. Everything routes to "considered harmful" or "top 10 reasons not to use" or "consider not using csh". :-)